# Why is the remote method signature differ from the specification in RPC?

Tags: c, rpc

I'm new to RPC. In the specification file, .x file, i write one method that accepts a sqaure_in struct and returns square_out struct. But here is what makes me vague, when i call the remote method, squareproc_1, from the client file, i passed a pointer not the value of the struct but in the specification file the method accepts struct square_in not a pointer, so why is that happening?

client.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    CLIENT *c1;
    square_in in;
    square_out *outp;

    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: client <HOST NAME> <integer-value>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    c1 = clnt_create(argv[1], SQUARE_PROG, SQUARE_VERS, "tcp");

    in.arg1 = atoi(argv[2]);
    if((outp = squareproc_1(&in, c1))  == NULL) {
        printf("%s", clnt_sperror(c1, argv[1]));
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("result: %ld\n", outp->res1);
    exit(0);
}
```

square.x

```
struct square_in {
    long arg1;
};

struct square_out {
    long res1;
};

program SQUARE_PROG {
    version SQUARE_VERS {
        square_out SQUAREPROC(square_in) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x31230000;
```

Comment: This is just "as it works", it accepts a pointer. There's not much more to understand about it. This is the usual way in C for passing a structure (as a pointer to it), otherwise, for large structures, very much data had to be copied on the stack.

Comment: @Ctx, how does the server get the input(arg1) from the pointer, does it need to communicate the client?

Comment: Henok, not the pointer is sent but the actual data! squareproc_1 fetches the data from the memory location you pass, serializes it and puts it on the wire.